# I have an Access MDB, I know the password, but how do I Disable it in Access 2013

Tags: microsoft-access, password-recovery

I have searched around but cannot find how to remove the password on my MDB file using Access 2013.

I do know the password so I can open the MDB Ok, but I want to disable the password.

One Tut says go to the Security option in the menu. There is none.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

**I want to disable the password.**

Source [How to password protected database in Access 2013](http://blogmines.com/blog/password-protect-access-2013-database/)

If you want to remove the password, then navigate to Info menu and select Decrypt Database.

[image]

Then enter the password to remove the password protection for Access Database.

**When trying to save that resulting database I cannot as I get the following message "You are trying to convert an encoded database. Decode the database, then try again"**

Source [Overview of Access security (MDB)](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/overview-of-access-security-mdb-HP005188226.aspx)

> **Encoding/decoding**
>
> The simplest method of protection is to encode the database. Encoding a database compacts the database file and helps protect it
>   from being read by a word processor. Encoding a database that employs
>   no security measures has no effect, because anybody can open the
>   database and gain full access to all objects in the database. Encoding
>   is particularly useful when you transmit a database electronically, or
>   when your store it on floppy disk, tape, or compact disc.
>
> Before you can encode or decode a Microsoft Access database, you must be either the owner of the database or, if the database employs
>   security measures, a member of the Admins group of the workgroup
>   information file that contains the accounts used to help protect the
>   database. You must also be able to open the database in exclusive
>   mode, which means you must have Open/Run and Open Exclusive
>   permissions.
>
> Decoding a database reverses the encoding.

To encode/decode the database:

```
File > Info > Users and Permissions > Encode/Decode Database
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did try that previously however when trying to save that resulting database I cannot as I get the following message ; 

You are trying to convert an encoded database. Decode the database, then try again.